# geom_smooth ignoring group?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a spaghetti plot with data like so:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=rep(1:100,20),
                  y=rnorm(1000),
                  z = rep(1:20,each=100))
p <- ggplot(data = dat,aes(x=x,y=y,group=z))
p <- p + geom_line()
p
```

Where each group z is a time series. Can I plot one geom_smooth() that is the mean value of the time series? I thought that this would work:

```
datMean <- aggregate(dat$y~dat$x, FUN=mean)
names(datMean) <- c("x","y")
p <- p + geom_smooth(data=datMean)
p
```

But it does not.

To be clear(er), I want this line through the original plot:

```
ggplot(data = datMean,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_smooth()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `ggplot(data = dat,aes(x, y)) + geom_line(aes(group = z)) + geom_smooth()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't work because there is no z column in datMean.
Place the group aesthetic in the geom_line only.

```
p <- ggplot(data = dat,aes(x=x,y=y))
p <- p + geom_line(aes(group=z))
```

Then this call will work

```
p <- p + geom_smooth(data=datMean)
p
```